# Wants to send push notification using one signal when new document is added in the flutter app.Should I use launchUrl() method for it?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, push-notification, onesignal

Below is the AddNewDocument.dart file. Whenever I add any document it should show new push notification to the user and should navigate to document details page. Is there any method to implement this?

```
import 'package:AtDocHUB/Controller/DocumentController.dart';
import 'package:AtDocHUB/Model/Document.dart';
import 'package:AtDocHUB/View/Document/DocumentPage.dart';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:form_field_validator/form_field_validator.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:jiffy/jiffy.dart';

DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(now);

//import 'package:flutter_text_form_field/flutter_text_form_field.dart';
class AddNewDocument extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    return _AddNewDocumentState();
  }
}

class _AddNewDocumentState extends State<AddNewDocument> {
  late final String date1;

  late String datainput;

  final List<String> items1 = ["Open", "Closed", "Cancel", "Submitted"];
  String? selectedItem;

  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  

  TextEditingController docTitleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController tokenNoController = TextEditingController();
  
  TextEditingController partyNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController startDateController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController endDateController = TextEditingController();
  late String docType = docTypeController.text;

  final List<String> items = [
    "Residential",
    "Commercial",
  ];
  String? selectedValue;

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _addDividersAfterItems(List<String> items) {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _menuItems = [];
    for (var item in items) {
      _menuItems.addAll(
        [
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: item,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                item,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //If it's last item, we will not add Divider after it.
          if (item != items.last)
            const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              enabled: false,
              child: Divider(),
            ),
        ],
      );
    }
    return _menuItems;
  }

  List<int> _getDividersIndexes() {
    List<int> _dividersIndexes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < (items.length * 2) - 1; i++) {
      //Dividers indexes will be the odd indexes
      if (i.isOdd) {
        _dividersIndexes.add(i);
      }
    }
    return _dividersIndexes;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    docStatusController.dispose();
    docTypeController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Future<Document>? _futureDocument;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 87, 156),
        title: Text('Add New Document'),
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: BackButtonIcon(),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => DocumentPage()))),
      ),
      body:
          //Container(

          SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: (_futureDocument == null)
                ? buildColumn()
                : buildFutureBuilder(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Form buildColumn() {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            minLines: 1,
            maxLines: 3,

            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,

            inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                  RegExp("[ ',-/ a-z A-Z á-ú Á-Ú 0-9]")),
            ],

            controller: docTitleController,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                ),
                labelText: 'Document Title',
                hintText: 'Document title required'),

            // validator: ,
            validator:
                MultiValidator([RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Required*')]),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Wrap(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                child: TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  minLines: 1,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  inputFormatters: [
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(14)
                  ],
                  controller: tokenNoController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
                      counterText: "",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                      labelText: 'Token No',
                      hintText: 'Token no required'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter token No';
                    } else if (value.length < 14) {
                      return 'Please enter 14 digits number';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 15,
              ),
            
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: TextFormField(
              minLines: 1,
              maxLines: 4,
              inputFormatters: [
                LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(50),
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-z A-Z]")),
              ],
              controller: partyNameController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Party Name',
                  hintText: 'Party name required'),
              validator:
                  MultiValidator([RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Required*')]),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                child: TextFormField(
                  //  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  //FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[- 0-9]")),
                  inputFormatters: [
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[- 0-9]")),
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)
                  ],
                  controller: startDateController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                    ),
                    labelText: 'Start Date',
                    hintText: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                  ),
                  onTap: () async {
                    DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                      context: context,
                      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                      firstDate: DateTime(
                          1991), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
                      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
                      // onConfirm:widget.onChanged,
                    ).then((pickedDate) {
                      if (pickedDate != null) {
                        // print(
                        // pickedDate); //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
                        String formattedDate =
                            DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickedDate);

                        print(formattedDate);

                        setState(() {
                          startDateController.text = formattedDate;
                          //set output date to TextField value.
                        });
                        print(startDateController.text);
                      } else {
                        print("Date is not selected");
                      }
                    });
                    final int dur = int.parse(durationController.text);
                    var stDate = DateTime.parse(startDateController.text);

                    var jiffy = Jiffy(stDate).add(
                      months: dur,
                      days: -1,
                      // days: 1095,
                    );
                    DateTime d = jiffy.dateTime;
                    String s = jiffy.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
                    setState(() {
                      endDateController.text = s.toString();
                    });
                  },

                  validator: MultiValidator(
                      [RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Required*')]),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 13,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                child: TextFormField(
                  // maxLength: 8,
                  // autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  autofocus: false,
                  controller: endDateController,
                  inputFormatters: [
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[- 0-9]")),
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)
                  ],
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
                      // prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                      counterText: "",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                      labelText: 'End Date',
                      hintText: ' yyyy-MM-dd'),
                  onTap: () async {},

                  validator: MultiValidator(
                      [RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Required*')]),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            //  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: TextFormField(
              minLines: 1,
              maxLines: 4,

              // autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
              inputFormatters: [
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-z A-Z 0-9]")),
                // FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(50)
              ],
              controller: rentDescController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Rent Description',
                  hintText: 'Rent Description required'),
              // validator:
              //     MultiValidator([RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Required*')]),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(

              //alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 35,
              width: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 89, 168),
              ),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  formKey.currentState?.validate();
                  final isValidForm = formKey.currentState!.validate();
                  if (isValidForm) {
                    //formKey.currentState?.validate();
                    // final int docId = int.parse(docIdController.text).toInt();
                    final String docTitle = docTitleController.text;
                    final int tokenNo =
                        int.parse(tokenNoController.text).toInt();
                    //final String tokenNo = tokenNoController.text;
                    final String partyName = partyNameController.text;
                    final String startDate = startDateController.text;
                    final String endDate = endDateController.text;

                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => DocumentPage()));

                    setState(() {
                      _futureDocument = createDocument(
                        // docId,
                        docTitle,
                        tokenNo,
                       startDate,
                        endDate,
                        //  createdAt,
                      );
                    });
                    // }
                  }
                },
                child: const Text("Save"),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 89, 168))),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
    //])
    //);
  }

  FutureBuilder<Document> buildFutureBuilder() {
    return FutureBuilder<Document>(
      future: _futureDocument,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(snapshot.data!.docTitle);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        }

        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the main.dart file where I have initialised App Id and other required things.Push Notification is coming in app properly and when I tap on the notification it opens the application. But i wants to show push notification when the new document is added to the app and when user tap on that particular notification it should navigate user to the document details page.I have also attached AddNewDocumentFile.dart.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:onesignal_flutter/onesignal_flutter.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'View/LoginPage.dart';
import 'View/homePageAdmin.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SharedPrefService.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class SharedPrefService {
  static late SharedPreferences pref;

  static Future<void> init() async {
    pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var usrEmail = pref.getString('email');
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    OneSignal.shared.setAppId('e89acaa4-5388-4e3a-bd69-44d197bdcbd7');
    OneSignal.shared
        .promptUserForPushNotificationPermission()
        .then((accepted) {});
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var usrEmail = SharedPrefService.pref.getString('email');

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
       
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: usrEmail == null ? LoginPage() : homePageAdmin(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the `OneSignal.shared.postNotification(notification);` after your `createDocument` function completes.

Comment: What is the value will be there of 'notification' in postNotification(notification)?

Comment: It will be a notification object with the title and other properties that you want to send in the notification.

Comment: Can you please tell how to navigate user to the particular page when user tap on the notification?

Comment: you can easily use Navigator.push command to navigate to specific page when you intercept the notification click.